# Why does this regex matches 0,00 if there's no Ungreedy modifier?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

```
^((1000,00)|(0?\d{1,3},\d{2}))$
```

This regex is supposed to match from '0,01' to '1000,00', allowing leading zeros, like '0001,01'

I know how to fix the regex, that's not the problem, what bothers me is the fact that the `0?` is not being greedy in the string `0,00`. It should 'eat' the 0 and leave nothing left for `\d{1,3}` to match, thus making the string invalid.

Yet this doesn't happen, and I want to know why.

Comment: I also know that the regex is wrong in some ways, but my question remains.

Comment: The `?` operator "should" not eat the 0, it "can" eat the 0!

Comment: Effect of backtracking?

Comment: I see now, the greedy modifier still gives back, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`?` *is* greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Initially, `0?` matches the first `0`. But as the matching fails afterwards due to `\d{1,3}`, the engine gives up this match and backtracks. If you don't want the engine to give up the match, use a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
^((1000,00)|(0?+\d{1,3},\d{2}))$
               ^
```

> With a possessive quantifier, the deal is all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's greedy, but it doesn't mean the engine won't backtrack to try and match the pattern.

In your example, if `0?` matches the leading `0` in `0.00`, then the following `\d{1,3}` can't match anything, failing the match. The engine tests this first, but seeing as it fails tries to match without using `0`. In this case, a match is found that uses `\d{1,3},\d{2}`.